# Jmeter: File upload Issues while Jmeter scripting

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a scenario wherein I have to upload a .txt file which inserts records in database, for a batch job operation further. I am using Jmeter scripting to automate this flow. I think I have followed all the rules needed to upload a file but still I face this error:

```
Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error
```

Here are the details of scripting the file upload

[jmeter_fileUpload_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJBQS.png)

[jmeter_fileUpload_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJH9L.png)

and the html code showing the paramter name for the input type "file"

```
<input type="file" size ="40" name="filename" class="textinputgroup_input" title="Use Browse button to select the file.">
```

I am not sure where I have made the mistake. I have properly used the request attributes in the HTTP sampler as per the Fiddler.

I will not be able to record due to some firewall restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Your config looks good, just make sure that:

1. File exists under the `${filepath}`
2. `${filepath}` should contain either full path to the txt file being uploaded or the file needs to live in JMeter's "bin" folder

In case if it doesn't help, check *jmeter.log* and/or server-side log file to get some clues regarding what's wrong. It may be something like missing header or whatever. As a last resort try comparing the requests which are being sent by JMeter and real browser with a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://wireshark.org/) to detect the differences and apply the appropriate JMeter configuration so requests would be identical.

See [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article for more detailed instructions.